# Регистрация пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

День добрый. Возник вопрос, при регистрации пользователя нужно помимо записи его логина и пароля, записать в другую таблицу кое-какие дефолтные данные. Структура БД организована так, что у этих данных есть столбец с ИД пользователя.

Получается, что когда мы записываем данные из-под авторизованного пользователя, то в этот столбец уходит его ИД. Но как быть при регистрации? Если мы только что создали пользователя, еще не авторизованы, откуда взять ИД пользователя? Таблица users имеет поле auto_increment ИД пользователя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спросить у мускуля последний записанный айди

Полезные ссылки:

1. http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php
2. http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php